# jar resources in jnlp are not signed by same certificate ETRADE Pro app Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, certificate, signed

I've been scouring the net for an answer and the majority of the results require resigning the JAR files. The thing is I have no idea where they are located or even if I have any. *The error states that the JAR resources are IN the JNLP file* so I'm not really sure how that works.

This problem just started yesterday so it has to be a certificate that was added somehow onto my system that java is using to sign the jars in the JNLP file. Would deleted all certificates be a good idea?

The problem is that I'm not sure how to find them or delete them. I was able to open the Java Control Panel for java and I could see a list of certificates but it would not let me delete them. I did, however, delete the java cache but that did not fix the problem.

I noticed in my update center there is an Opera browser certificate. It wasn't there before and wondering now if somehow that is involved? This is a really messy situation I'm in and really need a fix as I use Etrade for my livelihood.

This is the text I get in the details of the error under the "Launch File" tab:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" codebase="https://cdnpro.etrade.net/etprocli_alt1/" href="" >
  <information>
    <title>Power E*TRADE Pro</title>
    <vendor>E*TRADE Securities LLC</vendor>
    <homepage href="https://cdnpro.etrade.net/etprocli/etrader.jnlp"/>
    <description>Power E*TRADE Pro</description>
    <description kind="short">Power E*TRADE Pro</description>
    <icon kind="splash" href="icon.icns"/>
    <icon href="etlogo.gif"/>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions />
  </security>
  <resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
    <j2se version="1.8" initial-heap-size="256m" max-heap-size="896m"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
    <j2se version="1.8" initial-heap-size="256m" max-heap-size="896m"/>
  </resources>

  <resources>
    <property name="sun.java2d.noddraw" value="true"/>
    <property name="sun.awt.disableMixing" value="true"/>
    <property name="jnlp.SSL_CA_CERTIFICATES_DIR" value="https://cdnpro.etrade.net/certs/CA/SonicMQCA.der"/>
    <property name="jnlp.com.abwg.configurl" value="https://cdnpro.etrade.net/etprocli_alt1"/>
    <property name="jnlp.smsession" value=""/>
    <property name="jnlp.username" value=""/>
    <property name="jnlp.prof" value="false"/>
    <property name="jnlp.multi_session" value="false"/>
        <j2se version="1.8" initial-heap-size="256m" max-heap-size="640m"/>
        <jar href="Client.jar.pack.gz"/>
        <jar href="Properties.jar"/>
        <jar href="thirdparty.jar.pack.gz"/>
    <jar href="nimbus.jar"/>
        <jar href="jexcel.jar"/>
    <jar href="jxbrowser-4.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="runtime.jar"/> 
  </resources>

  <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
    <jar href="jxbrowser-win-4.1.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
    <jar href="jxbrowser-win-4.1.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
    <jar href="jxbrowser-win-4.1.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Mac OS X" arch="x86_64">
    <j2se  version="1.8"  java-vm-args="-XstartOnFirstThread -Xmx896m"/>
    <jar href="jxbrowser-mac-4.1.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Mac OS X" arch="amd64">
    <j2se  version="1.8"  java-vm-args="-XstartOnFirstThread -Xmx896m"/>
    <jar href="jxbrowser-mac-4.1.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Mac OS X" arch="i386">
    <j2se version="1.8"  java-vm-args="-XstartOnFirstThread -Xmx896m"/>
    <jar href="jxbrowser-mac-4.1.jar"/>
  </resources>

  <resources os="Linux" arch="amd64">
    <jar href="jxbrowser-linux64-5.4.3.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Linux" arch="x86_64">
    <jar href="jxbrowser-linux64-5.4.3.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Linux" arch="x86">
    <jar href="jxbrowser-linux32-5.4.3.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Linux" arch="i386">
    <jar href="jxbrowser-linux32-5.4.3.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows">
            <nativelib href="jexcel-windows.jar"/>
  </resources>
        <application-desc main-class="com.etrade.proui.ProMain"></application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

This problem started yesterday and I've done nothing to my computer except install Opera web browser. My Etrade was working perfectly for a long time able to launch with no problems so I can't figure out why all of a sudden it gave me that error.
I tried completely removing java **JDK 8u212** verified it wasn't on my system then did a clean manual install of JDK 8u221. It was installed correctly with no problems so it's been really frustrating seeing the problem still there.

Are there residual files or these "certificates" left over on my system? How can I check which JAR resources are not signed by the same certificate and then sign them with the same one? If there is an easier way to just delete everything certificate/jar/java related and starting over with a fresh install I wouldn't mind doing that.

Many of the suggestions online state to simply force signing a jar file with key tools. I've tried opening key tools in the /bin directory of java with no success. I'm fairly new to the command prompt so I apologize if some terms go over my head. Thank you to everyone for any suggestions or help to this ugly problem.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be your problem. I am having the same problem yesterday and today. Called e-trade and their tech support said they are no longer supporting linux and I should change over to windows or mac. That won't happen.

I tried updating Java and that didn't help either. I tried 2 different browsers, no change. So, I figure its because of an update at Etrade and I am calling them back today and trying a different tech support person to try and get a better answer.

Comment: I called Etrade and it turns out that the problem is on their end. Apparently they've had a similar issue before and developers were able to fix the problem within a week or so.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to close this thread. Etrade finally fixed the problem from their end now. I was able to open my Etrade Pro fully and without any problems just like before. I hope others were also able to start it up again as well!

Answer (score 0):

And as of around May 13, 2021 or so they've broken it again.  Here's some notes from 2018:

Certs I see in JAR files:

- jxbrowser-4.1/META-INF/ETPROKEY.RSA-print:subject=/C=US/ST=New York/L=New York/O=ETRADE FINANCIAL CORPORATION/OU=Global Information Security4/CN=ETRADE FINANCIAL CORPORATION
- jxbrowser-linux32-5.4.3/META-INF/ETPROKEY.RSA-print:subject=/C=US/ST=New York/L=New York/O=ETRADE FINANCIAL CORPORATION/OU=Global Information Security/CN=ETRADE FINANCIAL CORPORATION
- jxbrowser-linux64-5.4.3/META-INF/ETPROKEY.RSA-print:subject=/C=US/ST=New York/L=New York/O=ETRADE FINANCIAL CORPORATION/OU=Global Information Security/CN=ETRADE FINANCIAL CORPORATION
- jxbrowser-win-4.1/META-INF/ETPROKEY.RSA-print:subject=/C=US/ST=New York/L=New York/O=ETRADE FINANCIAL CORPORATION/OU=Global Information Security4/CN=ETRADE FINANCIAL CORPORATION
- runtime/META-INF/ETPROKEY.RSA-print:subject=/C=US/ST=New York/L=New York/O=ETRADE FINANCIAL CORPORATION/OU=Global Information Security4/CN=ETRADE FINANCIAL CORPORATION

Linux certs are `OU=Global Information Security` while others are
`OU=Global Information Security4`